# Adding shadow effect on iText elements

Tags: java, itext, cell, shadow, rectangles

I have some problem with iText in Java. I need to produce a cell or rectangle with shadow just like in this example:

[image]

*4* and *60* are in some kind of cell or rectangle with shadow. I don't know how to do it. Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way probably is to use a `Chunk` with a generic tag and a `PdfPageEvent`. This way you'll get an event callback when the `Chunk` is positioned on the page. The callback will give you the coordinates (rectangle) of the `Chunk`, allowing you to paint a border and a shadow at the correct location.

An example of such an event handler to paint a black border and a gray shadow:

```
class ShadowEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    @Override
    public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document,
      Rectangle rect, String text) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        // Paddings for the border
        int paddingHorizontal = 20;
        int paddingVertical = 5;
        // Width of the shadow
        int shadowwidth = 5;
        // Calculate border location and size
        float left = rect.getLeft() - paddingHorizontal;
        float bottom = rect.getBottom() - paddingVertical;
        float width = rect.getWidth() + 2*paddingHorizontal;
        float height = rect.getHeight() + 2*paddingVertical;
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
        // Draw the shadow at the bottom
        canvas.rectangle(left + shadowwidth, bottom - shadowwidth, width, shadowwidth);
        canvas.fill();
        // Draw the shadow at the right
        canvas.rectangle(left + width, bottom - shadowwidth, shadowwidth, height);
        canvas.fill();
        canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
        // Draw the border
        canvas.rectangle(left, bottom, width, height);
        canvas.stroke();
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
}
```

This shows how to use the generic tag:

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, outfile);
pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new ShadowEvent());
doc.open();
Chunk c = new Chunk("60");
c.setGenericTag("shadow");
doc.add(c);
doc.close();
```

(Note that the `text` parameter of the `onGenericTag` method will contain the `String` that was set to the `Chunk` with `setGenericTag`. This is `"shadow"` in the example above. It allows to differentiate between different tags. Since we're just using 1 tag here, I'm not using the `text` parameter.)

The result of the example looks like this:

[image: Border with shadow]