# Creating a 3D shadow effect on images with itextpdf

Tags: java, itext

I want to create a 3D shadow effect on images that I place in a pdf. I am using itextpdf.
The question is similar to :
[Adding shadow effect on iText elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290487/adding-shadow-effect-on-itext-elements)

but with images and not texts.
My images are placed in table cells. As long as the table is not completed, no way to get the actual size of the image nor its coordinates in the page, this makes it tricky.
Any brilliant id ?
Thanks and regards,
Sylvain

Comment: Please show code of your drawing images in table cells.

Answer (score 0):

4 hours later, I found a way to do it using PdfCellEvent and drawing what I need inside the cell's padding.

```
static class ShadowRectangle implements PdfPCellEvent {
        public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect,
                               PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
            PdfContentByte lCb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];

            // Paddings for the border
        int paddingHorizontal = 8;
        int paddingVertical = 8;

        // Width of the shadow
        int shadowwidth = 7;

        // Calculate border location and size
        float left = rect.getLeft() + paddingHorizontal;
        float bottom = rect.getBottom() + paddingVertical;
        float width = rect.getWidth() - 2 * paddingHorizontal;
        float height = rect.getHeight() - 2 * paddingVertical;


        lCb.saveState();
        lCb.setColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
        // Draw the shadow at the bottom
        lCb.rectangle(left + shadowwidth, bottom - shadowwidth, width, shadowwidth);
        lCb.fill();
        // Draw the shadow at the right
        lCb.rectangle(left + width, bottom - shadowwidth, shadowwidth, height);
        lCb.fill();

        //lCb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
        // Draw the border
        //lCb.rectangle(left, bottom, width, height);

        lCb.stroke();
        lCb.restoreState();
    }
}
```

// And I fill the PdfPTable this way

```
PdfPTable lImages = new PdfPTable(NB_PICTURE_PER_ROW);
lImages.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

// ... in a loop

```
lImageBoucle = Image.getInstance(lFile.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + lTabPhotos[i]);
                PdfPCell lCell = new  PdfPCell();
                lCell.setImage(lImageBoucle);
                lCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                lCell.setPadding(8);

                PdfPCellEvent lShadowRectangle = new ShadowRectangle();
                lCell.setCellEvent(lShadowRectangle);
                lImages.addCell(lCell);
```